# How do I remove non-functional links from the Dash?

Tags: unity-dash, uninstall

I have dead (non-functional) links in my Dash, how do I manually remove them? They were created by an installation of a Java program via bash script.

Here is the script (if it helps): [Minecraft](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/07/ubuntu-minecraft-installer-script.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the files `~/.local/share/applications/Minecraft.desktop` and `/usr/share/applications/Minecraft.desktop` if they exist.

Comment: Interesting, ~/.local/share/applications/Minecraft.desktop was there and I removed it but the issue persists.

Comment: @Switchkick, have you rebooted, they sometimes persist until reboot, also they will still show up in your "Recent Programs" history until pushed out by new apps.  If they were installed systemwide the may also be in the other location listed in Florian's answer, check there as well

Comment: I restarted, and the other location held no icon, issue remains. I will be marking this as the correct answer as I'm sure in most instances it will be.

Comment: Is `grep Minecraft ~/.local/share/applications/* /usr/share/applications/*` printing anything?

Comment: It is: /home/USERNAME/.local/share/applications/alloc-installer.desktop:Name=Minecraft

Comment: Have a look at `~/.local/share/applications/alloc-installer.desktop` if you still need that.