# How can I remove icon of uninstalled application from application lens in Dash?

Tags: unity-dash, uninstall, cardapio

I installed cardapio and its icon was in launcher as well in application lens in dash.
When I unistalled cardapio, its icon vanished from the launcher (as it should) but the icon is still present in application lens in Dash.
Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: You should probably also file a bug towards the package you used for installation; packages should remove all traces (except maybe configuration) when uninstalled.

Comment: Did you log out and back in after the removal of cardapio. Changes to unity lenses might only happen after that.

Comment: yes, I did numerous times!
Unfortunately, the cardapio icon in applications lens is persistent!

Answer (score 7):

Well, with help from this [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161029/how-do-i-remove-non-functional-links-from-the-dash) question I carried out the suggestion of florian-diesch to

`grep cardapio ~/.local/share/applications/*`

and there was `cardapio.desktop`. I deleted it and now the `cardapio` icon does not show up any more among the applications in dash.

Thank you all for your willingness to help me solve my problem.

Comment: I have merged your accounts (N.B. it makes it easier to login to your original account if you use a registered login).  You can click the tick button against the answer that helps you - either this one or the other answer in this thread.  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. First I uninstalled the application, then I deleted all references from the following folder:

```
/usr/share/applications
/usr/local/share/applications
~/.local/share/applications
```

Rebooted....

If not install this MENU editor:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:caldas-lopes/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ezame
```

and delete unwanted icons.

Answer (score 1):

try to run in terminal

`sudo rm /usr/share/applications/cardapio.desktop`

this will remove it from launcher, after that:

`sudo apt-get remove cardapio && sudo apt-get autoremove`

Comment: why move to /opt (will stay there forever) instead of /tmp (will be removed on next boot) or directly delete?

Comment: @tucuxi i don't read that programm is removed ;), now i know and he can just remove it

Comment: Thank you for your immediate replies.
As I said, I have uninstalled the cardapio application. Its icon is not anymore in launcher. It only shows in (installed) application lens in dash.

Comment: @SteliosSk your'e welcome :D

Comment: @SteliosSk look at edited answer, may help

Comment: No result with the suggestions.
The cardapio icon in application lens is persistent!

Answer (score 1):

None of it worked for me.
What i did

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to run terminal
2. `sudo -i` to log in as superuser
3. enter your password
4. `cd .local/share/applications`
5. `ls -l`

   See if you see `<your_app>.desktop` in here.  If you do, then issue
   `rm -f -r <your_app>.desktop` to delete the file