# Uninstall Emacs

Tags: 14.04, emacs

I have downloaded and installed emacs from the homepage and now want to unistall and reinstall it. When i do `remove` `purge` or `autoremove` the emacs icon is still to see at the sidebar left, but the terminal says that `package emacs is not installed so not removed`. How can i completely unistall emacs and all related data?

Comment: How exactly did you install it (from source or as a pre-compiled binary)?

Comment: i installed it from a tar.gz package from the homepage of emacs

Answer (score 1):

If you installed from Emacs website it means you installed by the sources, right?
When installing from source usually people uninstall by runnning:

```
sudo make uninstall
```

To avoid this kind of problems in the future start using the [CheckInstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CheckInstall) package which keeps track of all files installed by a "make install" or equivalent, creates a Debian package with those files, and adds it to the installed packages database, allowing for easy package removal or distribution.

To remove the icon from Dash you can follow the instructions from this another [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161029/how-do-i-remove-non-functional-links-from-the-dash) question:

> Remove the files `~/.local/share/applications/Emacs.desktop` and `/usr/share/applications/Emacs.desktop` if they exist.